# Changing the value of a td cell after clicking a button javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Note that some of the HTML has been omitted. I am trying to change the value in the td cell with id "name" to 0 after I click on the button labeled undo. I'm having trouble figuring it out. I need it to change so that the user sees 0. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="toUndo.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="undo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <body>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="results" id="first">
  <td>First Place</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="name"/></td>

    </tr>
    <button id="undo">undo</button>  
    <script type="text/javascript">undoName();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

java script file: toUndo.js

```
function clearIt {
document.getElementById("name").value = 0;
}
```

java script file: undo.js

```
function undoName {
undoButton = document.getElementById("undo");
undoButton.onclick = clearIt;
```

}

Comment: A quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=change+input+value+with+javascript) would have yielded the answers you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done like this...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function clearIt() {

document.getElementById("name").value = 0;
}

</script>

  <body >
  <table>
    <tr class="results" id="first">
  <td>First Place</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="name"/></td>

    </tr>
</table>
    <button id="undo" onclick='clearIt()'>undo</button>  
</body>
</html>
```

the mistake you are making is , missing the brackets after the function declaration , it must be `function undoName(){...` and `clearIt(){...` not `function undoName{...` and `clearIt{...`

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax errors in the Javascript code. See the attached code snippet.

```js
function clearIt() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("name"));
 document.getElementById("name").value = '0';
}

function undoName() {
 undoButton = document.getElementById("undo");
 undoButton.onclick = clearIt;
}
undoName();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="results" id="first">
      <td>First Place</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="name"/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 <button id="undo">undo</button>
</body>
```